# Is there any way to delete all the contents of a database created from SQLite3 usign python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have created a database using SQLite3 on Python. However, as and when I have to rerun the entire code, I have to delete the .db file. Is there any way to delete all the contents of the database file without having to delete the .db file everytime?

Comment: There's a way in C, but the python sqlite bindings don't export it. Easiest to just delete the file. Or query table names from the `sqlite_master` table and drop each one in a loop.

Comment: When dropping all tables first turn off foreign key constraints using `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0`.  Otherwise you would need to drop tables in a particular order based on foreign key relationships.  Just remember to turn it back on after recreating the schema... assuming it was on to start with.